# strange behaviour calling method of wcf from powershell using new-webproxyservice

Tags: wcf, powershell

Can someone explain this to me:

I builded an really simple wcf service for testing purposes.
Consuming service from powershell using New-WebServiceProxy I found this stange behaviour:

if in wcf service I have this kind of Contract returning an `int`:

```
[OperationContract]
int GetDictionaryLength();
```

calling this method in powershell gives an error and the definition of the method is not what I would expect to see

```
PS C:\ps> $a | Get-Member getdictionarylength | fl *
```

> TypeName   :
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1_022s_pwdservice_svc_wsdl.PWDService
>
> Name       : GetDictionaryLength
>
> MemberType : Method
>
> Definition : **System.Void**
>   GetDictionaryLength(System.Int32&,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   GetDictionaryLengthResult,
>   System.Boolean&, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   GetDictionaryLengthResultSpecified)

changing the contract like this:

```
[OperationContract]
string GetDictionaryLength();
```

do a great job called in powershell.

Why this?

WCF is in .net 4.0
Powershell is V2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Experimenting with your answer, and then finally discover [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5033317/110549), it seems all your problems will go away if you simply add [XmlSerializerFormat] to the operation contract, and the method signature will return to normal. At least my problems did when testing against a 2.0 .Net framework and powershell.

Comment: Could you give an example, how it can look to add [XmlSerializerFormat] to the operation contract?

Answer (score 1):

finally I've discovered this:

```
PS C:\ps> [int]$int = 0
PS C:\ps> $bool = $true
PS C:\ps> $a.DictionaryLength([ref]$int, [ref]$bool)
PS C:\ps> $int
61
```

I've build a solution with .net 2.0 (powershell native framework) for a client application to consume my wfc (.net 4.0)
and the definition for method DictionaryLegth() was:

```
void myservice.DictionaryLength(out int DictyionaryLengthResult, out bool DictonaryLengthSpecified)
```