# Strangeness with powershell and WCF service

Tags: powershell, wcf

I've noticed a strange occurence when calling a WCF service method from a Powershell script.
I've implemented a basic service with one method as shown below:

```
 public int receive_data(string machine_name, string ad_site, string user_name,string version)
    {  //do some stuff in here  }
```

This method takes 4 parameters as shown.

However, when creating an object of this service in powershell and doing a |GM to display it I see the following:

```
receive_data                         Method     void receive_data(string machine_name, string ad_site, string user_name, string version, [ref] int receive_dataResult, [ref] bool receive_d...
```

This shows that 2 other [Ref] parameters are needed. The powershell will not submit without these two extra parameters.

My question is what are the parameters? Why are they needed and dont appear against the Service?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888610/why-is-powershell-adding-additional-parameters-to-web-service-method-signatures maybe this helps

Comment: @Paul - thats exactly it!